# Predicting a Sequence of Truncated Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

Given a hidden system $x_{n+1} = x_n + c$ with the observed $y_n$ being the whole part of $x_n$ (meaning everything to the left of the decimal place) and $y_m, \dots, y_n$ have been observed.  I want to approximate $y_{n+1}$.  I don't know $c$.

I prefer a solution that works for real numbers. If the solution is constrained to rational numbers, that's fine.  If it's constrained to integers I'll work with it.  I don't mind mapping to a different space to solve the problem. I can stand a few erroneous predictions (the sequence is observed sequentially with each number predicted before its appearance), but over time I need to reduce the number of errors as much as possible.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The statement of what you want doesn't make much sense. What is $\Delta$? Why do $y_1,...,y_{n-1}$ appear in the problem when they have nothing to do with $y_{n+1}$? What are the $x_n$'s?

Comment: Is it crazy to say the best thing to do is just to do a linear regression on the $y_k$, extrapolate one more term, and round? If you have a bunch of points estimating an unknown underlying slope ($c$ in this case) of a line, a linear regression should do as well as possible in estimating that underlying slope, and therefore the correct answer. Maybe there are solutions that perform better locally, but in general I'm pretty sure that this is the best solution.

Comment: That would give a good approximation of $c$ but wouldn't do well in predicting the next $y$.  To do that you need to know the current $x$ and the current $c$ because you don't know if the decimal part of the current $x$ is about to overflow into a whole number when you add $c$.